# Show some number $M$ exists for $|A^k|_{ij} ≤ M$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation

Suppose that $A$ is diagonalizable. Show that if all eigenvalues are either $±1$ or $0$, then there is some number $M$ such that $|A^k|_{ij} ≤ M$ for all $k$.

I'm having a hard time with this question here. I think I have an idea of how to solve it, but I need help carrying out the steps.

I think I need to find $A = PDP^{−1}$ since it diagonalizable. Then I need to find $A^k$ for all $k$. Then I have to show that some number $M$ exists for this.

For the first part here is what I have:

$A=PDP^{−1}$

$A^{k}=(PD^kP^{-1})$ for $k>0$.
where D is diagonal of eigenvalues of $A$, which could be $+1$ or $-1$ or $0$, and $P$ is columns of eigenvectors of $A$. And, $A^kx = λ^kx$. Since some $λ$ could be $0$, have that $A$ not invertible. And since $A^{k}=(PD^kP^{-1})$, $A$ is bounded by $P$ and $P^-1$?
Also, $(A^k)_{ij}$ = $(a^k)_{ij}$, an entry in $i$th row and $j$th column of $A^K$. This entry can be expressed in terms of $(A^k)_{ij} =(P_{ij}D^k_{ij}P^{-1}_{ij})$. And $|A^k|_{ij}$ is given by $sqrt((P_{ij}D^k_{ij}P^{-1}_{ij})^2)$

I'm stuck here... Do I need to somehow incorporate the values of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors? Can someone please guide me towards finding the solution, I'm pretty confused. I'm also not sure how to show that $M$ exists.

Comment: $A=PDP^{-1}$ then $A^k=PD^kP^{-1}$. So entries of $A^k$ are bounded in terms of entries of $P, P^{-1}$

Comment: Note that $A^3=A$. So, it suffices to consider only the entries of $A$ and $A^2$.

Comment: @markvs I made some changes, am I on the right track, what should I do next?

Comment: @user1551 I tried to add some more to the solution, what should I do now?

Answer (score -1):

Since $A$ is a diagonalisable matrix whose eigenvalues are $\pm1$ or $0$, it is annihilated by the polynomial $x(x-1)(x+1)=x^3-x$. Hence $A^3=A$ and the seemingly infinite set $\{A,A^2,A^3,\ldots\}$ is actually finite and equal to $\{A,A^2,A^3\}$. Thus one can take $M$ as the maximum modulus of the entries of $A,A^2$ and $A^3$.